# How do I create a SQL Agent Alert on a custom error message in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql, sql-server-agent, alerts, raiserror

I want operators to be notified when I throw a custom error message. My understanding is that I need to add a message to sys.messages, then I can either `RAISERROR` or `THROW` that error ID. Creating an alert on the message ID and setting it to send to operators should create those notifications.

I've created a SQL Agent alert on the message ID of 50005, and am using the following T-SQL to create the message:

```
EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50005,
          @severity = 16,
          @msgtext = N'%s';
GO
```

Then, if I execute this:

```
RAISERROR (50005, -- Message id.
       16, -- Severity,
       1, -- State,
       N'My custom message');
THROW 50005, 'My custom message', 1;
GO
```

I get the following output as expected from both `RAISERROR` and `THROW`:

> Msg 50005, Level 16, State 1, Line 68
>   My custom message

When I view the history of the alert though, it shows that it has not been triggered, and the operator does not receive an email update.

My agent alert looks like this:

[image: Agent Alert Setup]

Scripting the alert generates the following:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_alert @name=N'Alert DBA on custom errors', 
    @message_id=50005, 
    @severity=0, 
    @enabled=1, 
    @delay_between_responses=0, 
    @include_event_description_in=1, 
    @database_name=N'', 
    @notification_message=N'', 
    @event_description_keyword=N'', 
    @performance_condition=N'', 
    @wmi_namespace=N'', 
    @wmi_query=N'', 
    @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_notification @alert_name=N'Alert DBA on custom errors', @operator_name=N'My Operator', @notification_method = 1
GO
```

For your convenience, if you try to recreate my issue this will help you drop from sys.messages:

```
sp_dropmessage @msgnum = 50005; 
GO
```

Comment: What does your Agent alert definition look like?

Comment: I've updated the question to include a screenshot and the alert scripted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please refer to [Create a User-Defined Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175021.aspx)

> By default, user-defined messages of severity lower than 19 are not sent to the Microsoft Windows application log when they occur. **User-defined messages of severity lower than 19 therefore do not trigger SQL Server Agent alerts.**

So your message should be

```
EXEC sp_addmessage @msgnum = 50005,
      @severity = 1,  -- Informational messages that return status information or report errors that are not severe. The Database Engine does not raise system errors with severities of 0 through 9.
      @msgtext = N'%s';
GO
```

When you use [`THROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx), it defaults to severity 16 which does not fire the alert.

```
RAISERROR (50005, -- Message id.
       1, -- Severity,
       1, -- State,
       N'My custom message') with log;
```

---

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Alert [Alert DBA on custom errors]    Script Date: 1/22/2016 3:17:22 PM ******/
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_alert @name=N'Alert DBA on custom errors', 
        @message_id=50005, 
        @severity=0, 
        @enabled=1, 
        @delay_between_responses=0, 
        @include_event_description_in=0, 
        @database_name=N'AdventureWorks2012_test', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized]', 
        @job_id=N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
GO
```

[image]

Also, make sure you use `@delay_between_responses` to a sensible value so that your inbox is not flooded with emails.

Also, refer to my answer for [Monitoring free space in SQL Server data files](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97472/8783) using user defined message and alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "with log" to your raiserror statement will make the alert fire.

```
RAISERROR (50005, -- Message id.
       16, -- Severity,
       1, -- State,
       N'My custom message') WITH LOG;
```

you will need sysadmin or alter trace to use with log(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)