# Why "Data File(s) Used Size (KB)" PerfMon counter doesn't exist?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, perfmon

I wanted to create my own SQL Server baseline by collecting data with the Performance Monitor.

Among all counters that I have decided to monitor, I also wanted to have a historic trend about data file(s) growth for each database, but, unfortunately, there's no counter for that. I only have a "Data File(s) Size (KB)" counter, but that refers to the space that the database takes in advance, not the one that is actually using.

I know already that i can get the actual used size by doing some queries, in fact my question is not about *how* to retrieve that information but *why* can't i get it from the PerfMon.

Is there any official motivation for that? Laziness from Microsoft developers, some technical problem, or maybe something else?

Also note that I can get with no problem the used size for the log(s) file, which is kind of funny in my opinion!

[image: Missing counter]

Answer (score 4):

While it probably doesn't really answer your question I'll post it anyway, it may be more of a comment though.

I don't think anybody outside of Microsoft can give us a definitive reason why this counter was never added.

There is only minor feedback on this connect item asking for a similar thing, but it hasn't been closed as wontfix either:

["Percent Data Used" Performance Counter - by AussieJohn](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/303556/percent-data-used-performance-counter) in which Microsoft's last suggestion is:

> Bill: thanks for the suggestion. sp_spaceused provides this
>   information and much more. Do you want to expose all or a subset of
>   the following info in perfmon?
>
> 1. space reserved
> 2. space allocated
> 3. unused space that is reseved but not used
> 4. space allocation between index and data

If you really want to expose this information through perfmon you could look at user settable counters as suggested by [Marian](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/418/marian) in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/103481/39384)